# JUnit5 : restTemplate exchange method mocking

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, resttemplate

I’m trying to mock a method call inside the method:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

@Autowired @Qualifier(value = "restTemplateValue") 
RestTemplate restTemplate;

protected ResponseEntity<T> getResponse(final String endpoint, final E requestDTO, final HttpMethod httpMethod) {
    return getResponse(endpoint,requestDTO,HttpMethod httpMethod,this.restTemplate);
}


protected ResponseEntity<T> getResponse(final String endpoint, final E requestDTO, final HttpMethod httpMethod,RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    ...
    response = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint,httpMethod, requestDTO, type);
    ...
    return response;
}
}
```

I tried mocking the `restTemplate.exchange()` method from my test method, but it still calls the real exchange method.
Please suggest, how can I mock that line.

```
 Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(any(),any(),any(),any())
   .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: `restTemplate` is not a mock. `restTemplate.exchange(…)` is a real method call. `when(restTemplate.exchange(…))` will still call the real method, because it's a real method call and Java evaluates its arguments eagerly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MockRestServiceServer` from [Spring Test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client).

This way you can test the expected behaviour without having to run a Server or call the actual exchange method, like so (Example form the docs):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
mockServer.expect(requestTo("/greeting")).andRespond(withSuccess());

// Test code that uses the above RestTemplate ...

mockServer.verify();
```

You can also find a lot of Code examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/main/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/client/samples).